# Kubernetes How do I ensure that the canary-frontend hits the canary-backend and the stable frontends only hit the stable backends?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

If I have multiple deployments of a stable frontend & stable backend, and 1 deployment each of canary-frontend and canary-backend,

How do I ensure that the canary-frontend hits the canary-backend and the stable frontends only hit the stable backends?

I'm thinking that session affinity will only ensure that someone loggedin on my canary-frontend will return to my canary frontend, but it doesnt guarantee me that the canary-frontend will hit the canary backend.

Is there something such as a 'label affinity'?

Note I am using google container engine if that matters

Comment: How do you connect your frontend to your backend? Do you have some environment configuration for the IP/service name? Do you discover the service using kubernetes?

Comment: kubernetes handles my service discovery for me. my backend-service can be accessed at `https://backend-service`. However the stable `backend-service` will obviously have different routes (or different logic) then the canary `backend-service`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have your canary deployment named `canary-backend-service` and the canary frontend should call `https://canary-backend-service`.

You can have an environment variable to switch between the stable and canary backend service, a bit like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: canary-frontend
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontend
          image: frontend:v2.0.0-rc1
          env:
            - name: BACKEND
              value: canary-backend
```

Then you will have to read the `BACKEND` environment variable in your code instead of a fixed `backend-service` hostname.

Comment: That wouldnt work since kubernetes wouldnt know to send some users to my canary vs my stable website